# Web test runner built in server configure

Tags: web, test-runner

How to configure built in server in web test runner to use https and run at custom url i.e. host
What changes are required in test runner config?

I tried various options like in web test runner config
Default export {
https: true,
hostname:'example.com',
port:9000,
sslKey:"path to key pem",
sslCert:"path to cert",
}